# « Quel/quoi que » suivi du verbe « être » : identité ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms-relatifs, syntaxe

> *Quelles que* soient les émotions, elles sont souvent intenses.

Le pronom relatif indéfini « [quel que](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/21570/la-grammaire/les-homophones-grammaticaux/les-homophones-quelque-et-quel-que) » signifie toujours « n’importe quel » ou « peu importe » (BDL) et il est ici attribut du nom *émotions*, féminin pluriel, avec lequel il s'accorde.

> *Quoi que* soient les émotions, elles sont souvent intenses.
> *Quoi que* soit les émotions, elles sont souvent intenses.

Ces deux phrases sont-elles grammaticalement/syntaxiquement cohérentes et ont-elles le même sens que la première : pourquoi ou pourquoi pas ?

Comment: Je vous invite à vous mouiller plus directement avec l'accord du verbe. Merci !

Comment: https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/quoique-ou-quoi-que/

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que dans un cas on parle des émotions spécifiques (par exemple, *l'amour et la haine, quels qu'ils soient*), alors que dans l'autre cas il s'agit d'un niveau d'abstraction plus élevé, où on parle d'un groupe entier d'émotions - "vos angoisses, quoi que soit/soient ces émotions".

Je dirais que *quoi que soient* est l'option intermédiaire... mais aussi la plus suspecte.

Pour la transparence, j'avoue qu'il s'agit ici d'une perspective de non-francophone.

Comment: Est-ce que vous êtes LE Roger Vadim, célèbre acteur de cinéma de Dieu créa la femme?

Comment: @Maurice il est décédé, il y a quelques temps déjà. Mais j'ai beaucoup d'admiration pour lui. Ça a été un peu presumptuous de moi d'adopter ce nom sur SE, mais à l'époque je ne fréquentait pas encore le French SE.

Answer (score 1):

Dans un cas  (quelles que) on réfère à un choix quelconque parmi les émotions, des choses connues dans l'ensemble en tant que catégorie, cela en disant que ce choix n'a pas d'incidence dans le propos. Dans l'autre (quoi que) on réfère à la nature de ces choses que l'on appelle émotions et que l'on ne connait pas ou que l'on connait seulement imparfaitement en tant que catégorie, cela en disant que cette nature est considérée comme n'ayant pas d'incidence dans le propos.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux phrases commençant par *quoi que* ne sont pas du bon français. Je suis un francophone de naissance. Et je n'utiliserais jamais cette expression « quoi que soient les émotions. »

Je ne sais pas pourquoi...

Comment: Je suis aussi francophone, ça me dérange aussi, mais ce n'est pas suffisant, je veux savoir pourquoi, en particulier depuis que [j'ai vu ça dans un ouvrage](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Les_quiz_du_Petit_bon_usage/qWOqDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22quoi+que+soient%22&pg=PA112&printsec=frontcover) (ex. 2 et 7 p. 112) publié chez Boeck et édité par deux docteurs en linguistique. Certainement [inusité](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quoi+que+soient%2Cquelles+que+soient%2Cquels+que+soient&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) mais est-ce erroné et pourquoi ?

Comment: Ma piste de solution ? _Quoi que_ vaut pour _quelle que soit la chose que/qui_... _ou peu importe ce que/qui_ ([BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/21571/la-grammaire/les-homophones-grammaticaux/les-homophones-quoique-et-quoi-que)).

Comment: Il me semble qu'on peut dire "quoi qu'on dise" ou quoi qu'on fasse", mais pas "quoi que soient les émotions"

Comment: En substituant avec _être_ on obtient : _quelle que soit la chose qui soit les émotions_ ou _peu importe ce que soit les émotions_. À mon avis c'est là où le bât blesse mais j'aimerais comprendre pourquoi. Dans le premier cas il y a redondance, dans le deuxième, le temps est inadéquat. J'ai choisi à dessein le verbe être parce que je sais que les exemples dont tu parles, eux, sont possibles.

Comment: Dans les rares exemples au ngram, on trouve il y 150 ans un auteur qui semble percevoir la nuance comme il utilise les deux dans la même phrase « Quels que soient et quoi que soient les hommes, le but des gouvernements est invariablement le même... ».  On peut être certain que dans son cas il ne se trompe pas entre l'un et l'autre. Vraiment étrange...

Comment: En effet, la perception du terme "quoi que" a peut-être changé au cours des ans. Aujourd'hui, personne ne dirait "quoi que soient les hommes". Mais j'ignore pourquoi.